# How do I compare different optimization algorithms when step-size is unknown?

Tags: algorithms

I wish to compare different optimization algorithms (gradient descent, Newton, quasi-Newton, conjugated gradient, etc) for a particular problem at hand.
My main focus is on speed of convergence.

The issue is that all methods rely on a step-size $\gamma$. How do I compare the speed of my algorithms when I don't know which $\gamma$ would work best for which model?

Comment: What if comparing their best cases (i.e. finding relatively best  for each method and then comparing their convergence speed)